# URL standard in web application

Tags: url, web-applications, intranet

What is the standard or conventional way to name a web application that is accessed by URL in intranet?

For eg, http: //hostname:port/App_Name2.0    // is this valid ? Can i add version number with the application name

Comment: What would happen when the version changes?

Comment: URL will also get changed .For eg, http: //hostname:port/App_Name3.0

Comment: What would happen to the old URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia provides an excellent outline on this topic ([URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)).

```
scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

Comment: I am asking whether it is standard to have version number to web application which will be reflected in URL ..?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that adding the version number to the URL would not be smart. I would rather display it in the title bar of my web application so that the user is informed of what version they are using. and as pointed out by @poitroae, a good URL can be formatted with those guidelines